# WPF basics doubts on attributes for binding source and target type

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I am new to WPF. I see different syntaxes at different place as below. Please find it below and help me understand.

This below one works and being used by many.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
```

However, this also equally works.

```
<Style TargetType="{TextBlock}">
```

So what's the significance of `x:Type` here?

Some people use in `ListView, Itemsource = "{Binding}"` while at some places, I need to use `Itemsource = "{Binding Propertyname}"`

My question is, at some places only when I use Propertyname, it displays the data and in some places, when I dont use propertyname but just Binding, it displays data. How and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I had to research your first question as I'm rusty on WPF.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx):

> WPF supports techniques that enable specifying the value of some properties of type Type without requiring an x:Type markup extension usage. Instead, you can specify the value as a string that names the type. Examples of this are ControlTemplate.TargetType and Style.TargetType. Support for this behavior is not provided through either type converters or markup extensions. Instead, this is a deferral behavior implemented through FrameworkElementFactory.

So the lack of "x:Type" is just a convenience provided by the XAML parsing functionality.

As to your second question, `Itemsource = "{Binding}"` will bind to whatever the DataContext is for that component.  `Itemsource = "{Binding Propertyname}"` binds to DataContext.Propertyname.  This is also equivalent to `Itemsource = "{Binding Path=Propertyname}"`

Might I suggest some [reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx)

Comment: Thank you NT, it helps me :) Any help on 1st question pls :( I am new to WPF :(

Comment: Thank you so much NT, that helps me a lot. I didn't researched on my own, sorry for the trouble. I will read the directions you gave, I appreciate your kind help :) Cheers....